# Realtime backtick output processing

Tags: perl

I don't know if this is possible but I'm working on sending the output of a command over sockets so it will be shown on both the client and server computer while the command is running. When I try to use backticks the output isn't saved into the variable until the command completes which is bad for when I run a command that takes a long time.

Question: Is there a way to scan the output on a line by line basis by say spawning another process and having it "watch" a variable?

Edit: This is what I tried with open

```
open DATA, "pause |" or die "Failed: $!";
while( defined(my $line = <DATA>)){
    chomp($line);
    print "$line\n";
}
```

I would like the output to be shown before the command completes.

Comment: I don't understand what sockets have to do with backticks. Do you want to read a program's STDOUT or a do you want to read a socket?

Comment: I want to be able to read stdout asynchronously and output as soon as a newline is added to stdout. The sockets part isn't important.

Comment: To read asynchronously from 1 or more input **then** send events to 0 or more clients, you have to work with *non blocking IO* and use `select` command to address all IO simultaneously...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have the right approach.

```
my @cmd = ( 'perl', '-e', '$|=1; for (1..5) { print "$_\n"; sleep 1; }' );

open(my $pipe, '-|', @cmd)
   or die("Can't launch child: $!\n");

while (defined( my $line = <$pipe> )) {
    chomp($line);
    print "<$line>\n";
}
```

When writing to STDOUT, most programs flush their output when a newline is encountered when STDOUT is a terminal ("line buffering"). Most programs fall back to block outputting chunks of 4 KiB or 8 KiB when STDOUT isn't a terminal ("block buffering"). That's why I had to use `$|=1;` in the child program in the example above.

Programs that behave as described can be fooled into using line buffering using pseudo-terminal instead of a pipe.

```
my @cmd = ( 'unbuffer', 'perl', '-e', 'for (1..5) { print "$_\n"; sleep 1; }' );

open(my $pipe, '-|', @cmd)
   or die("Can't launch child: $!\n");

while (defined( my $line = <$pipe> )) {
    chomp($line);
    print "<$line>\n";
}
```

[IPC::Run](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC::Run) provides a native method of creating pseudo-terminals.

```
use IPC::Run qw( run );

my @cmd = ( 'perl', '-e', 'for (1..5) { print "$_\n"; sleep 1; }' );

my $buf = '';
run(\@cmd, '>pty>', sub {
    $buf .= $_[0];
    while ($buf =~ s/^(.*)\r\n//) {
        print "<$1>\n";
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for introducing `unbuffer`. If I'd only known it before... But it must be installed, right? My Ubuntu says it's part of the `expect` package.

Comment: Do you think using `DATA` as the filehandle will work? The OP uses it but I'm suspicious because it's kind of reserved.

Comment: @PerlDuck, Yes, `unbuffer` needs to be installed, which is why I mentioned IPC::Run has a built-in method (for which I've added an example). /// Yes, `DATA` can be reopened. Of course, it's not a good idea to use `DATA` because it already has meaning, and because it's a global (not lexical) variable.

Comment: I have a somewhat unrelated question. Is it possible to set it to buffer on carriage returns as well?

Comment: A program can flush its buffers whenever it wants. I've described when most programs do it.

Comment: (`STDOUT->flush()` in Perl)